# How to enable a printer every 2 min with crontab

Tags: printing, cron

I want to enable a printer every 2 min. (it gets disabled for no reason after  some time)
I have done a cron job in crontab :

```
*/2 * * * * cupsenable -E myPrinter
```

But printer keeps being disabled.

the command cupsenable -E myPrinter works when I run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron` uses a minimal PATH (only `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, by default), so you need to provide it either in the command or as a parameter in cron.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/sbin/cupsenable -E myPrinter
```

===

I would suggest to check the log files in /var/log/ for a log file that gets updated when this happens and check why the printer is getting disabled. You might have a network problem or it might be the printer telling the system it has a problem. That problem is likely logged in /var/log/syslog.

Comment: [Turns out the PATH is actually hard-coded!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401622/22222) I was wondering about that after editing your answer so I asked on U&L.

Comment: Sourcing `.bashrc` would have been *really* bad design! PATHS have no business being set there, they belong in `~/.profile` anyway :) But yes, they could at least source `/etc/profile`! Who knows what they were thinking.